# Looking for a WinForms control that can represent time values

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, controls

I am looking for a third-party open source or commercial WinForms control that can represent the following values:

Total Duration of Task.
Time Elapsed.
Time Remaining.

Have not been able to find one.

Comment: have you tried the timer controll

Comment: This is well supported by standard controls.  A plain Label if you just want to display it.  An MaskedEditBox if you want to allow entry or editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `System.Diagnostic` Namespace there is a [`Stopwatch` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx), you should be able to use this to create your own control.

> A Stopwatch instance can measure elapsed time for one interval, or the total of elapsed time across multiple intervals. In a typical Stopwatch scenario, you call the Start method, then eventually call the Stop method, and then you check elapsed time using the Elapsed property.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Perhaps I should have phrased the question better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Infragistics is pretty popular for Winforms and has the option for its DateTimePicker

```
... setting the MaskInput to {time} should get the behavior you are looking for. 
If you only set the FormatString property, the the time will display only when 
the control is in edit mode (when the cursor is in the control).
```

from http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/4172.aspx.

But i think third party will be paid ones.

If you are looking for windows inhouse control DatePicker has a property Format that can be set to Time. Be sure to set ShowUpDown to True.

or

```
this.dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "hh:mm";
this.dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

.......

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.ToString());
}
```